# Automating with Chrome headless browser, required OTP everytime

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser, one-time-password

I am automating a application in selenium automation tool using java, with headless chrome.

My application needs OTP verification on first login in a computer or a new browser(chrome/mozila/IE). Once OTP verified on the machine or browser, from next time it will not request to enter OTP. Login is enough.

Since its headless browser which I am automating ,I thought I can give OTP and verify by entering OTP in console for first time and from next time it may not ask for OTP.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", constant.browserPathChrome);
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--enable-javascript");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("my application url");
```

But chrome headless keep asking for OTP everytime, when I launch the site from same machine even after verifying it first time in my machine by providing the received OTP in console as input. But everytime I can not give OTP when automating. how to make it behave like other browsers? which capability I should add?

Phantom.js doesnt have this kind of issue, when I give OTP via console for the first time, it takes verifies and from next time it doesnt ask for OTP. but due to some other reasons I am not able to use pahntom.js. I want to use chrome headless.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium will create a new instance of browser for each run, so it is valid that it asks OTP for each run.

One solution may be you can add a Chrome profile while initiating the browser instance, so that selenium will pick this profile instead of launching its default one.

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("user-data-dir=path_of_chrome_profile");
```

chrome profile path can be your local path or repository path

Comment: new instance requires logins, that is fine, but other browsers like chrome, phantom.js doesnt asks for OTP for second time.
chrome headless only asks for OTP

Comment: I am not used to Phantom.js. you can try adding profile and check if it solves your problem

Comment: As per https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/921 — , defining user data dir does not work it seems

Comment: I think that bug was way too old one. I am using the same (chromeOptions.addArguments("user-data-dir=path_of_chrome_profile");) to use profile in my script. you can try check the browser's "Profile Path" that it is same as the one you specified. Note: for checking you need to run the script in headful mode. Thanks